# After upgrade to Magento 2.3 - js error in arrays.js in cart and checkout

Tags: checkout, cart, javascript, upgrade, subtotal

I am updating an e-commerce with Magento, from version 2.1.18 to version 2.3.4 (I have verified that it also happens by updating to version 2.2.11).

Everything went well, but when I add a product to the cart I get the javascript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'after' of null
    at Object.insert (arrays.js:122)
    at collection.js:94
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at UiClass.insertChild (collection.js:91)
    at layout.js:433
    at Registry._resolveRequest (registry.js:418)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Registry._updateRequests (registry.js:400)
    at later (underscore.js:821)
```

[image: cart screenshot with js arrays.js error]

Same mistake if I go to checkout.

I am verifying that the subtotals of the order are not loaded, I do not know if it is the consequence of the error or the cause of the error.

- I have disabled and deleted all the installed modules;
- I have disabled all unnecessary modules of Magento 2.3.4;
- I have deleted my theme and I am using the Luma theme;
- I deleted cache, indexes and static files and created everything again,

but the problem is always there.

Comment: Please go to the network tab and check the response ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

please comment if it works!

Comment: on Magento 2.3 you need to force the creation of static content on command line
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

I had already said that it is one of the tests that I did, but that did not result in the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I finally found out how to fix it.

The problem is that the "Instant Purchase" is enabled. So you need to go to:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Instant Purchase -> Enabled (set this to NO)**

And that's it. I had been looking on how to fix this for 4 days without any luck. So I decided to go through all the Magento options.

I hope this might be useful for other people :)