# Magento2 blank Checkout Page with JS errors

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

Since a few months the Checkout Page show blank except of the logo. In the Browser console there are several JS errors. There are a few threads about this error but nothing helped. I did try fixing it by static-content:deploy and other command, but nothing really works as a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution and posted it on this question:
[After upgrade to Magento 2.3 - js error in arrays.js in cart and checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/306807/after-upgrade-to-magento-2-3-js-error-in-arrays-js-in-cart-and-checkout/329546#329546)

Hope it might be useful for some people.